# Web Api 2 CORS not working with POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, cors

According to [asp.net tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api), we only need following code to enable cors on `Web Api` application:

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*","*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Following is my code:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services  
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*","*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
    }
}
```

It is working fine for `Get`, but still it is giving error for `Post` requests

Following is the error, I am getting on Post:

> POST http://api.example.com/token 404 (Not Found) 
>   XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://api.example.com/token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header
>   is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.example.com'
>   is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code
>   404.

Comment: Does a non-CORS (same domain) POST request to the same resource succeed? Can we see your controller method?

Comment: It is same Domain. Web Api is just the subdomain of main domain, api.mydomain.com.

Comment: A subdomain is *not* the same domain.

Comment: Then var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*","*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors); should work?

Comment: I'm not even sure you're looking in the right direction. 404 error? Does the route even exist? WebApi routes are case-sensitive... are you sure you shouldn't be hitting `/Token`? ***Please*** show us your controller code/routing.

Comment: Can you show your request body?

Comment: I have put the request body on the question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the following to your Web.Config:

```
<httpProtocol>
   <customHeaders>
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
   </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Inside of the **System.webServer** config node.

Comment: New error : The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://www.example.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Try removing your code in the Register and run it.  If it doesn't work, see the following post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343384/the-access-control-allow-origin-header-contains-multiple-values

Comment: Once the NuGet package is added and CORS is working properly, this will cause the above error due to duplicate Allow-Origin headers being emitted.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors NuGet package to your project before the CORS settings in WebApiConfig will actually work.

Comment: Make sure you do NOT also have the <customHeaders> stuff in web.config.  You need the NuGet package and the stuff in WebApiConfig, but don't need anything telling IIS to do custom headers.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should write an action for post request in the controller

just like this

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post()
{
    //Do something here
}
```