# The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, google-chrome, cross-domain

i'm trying to send get request to api like it's a login url

```
var url = "http://demo.software.travel/gptp/api/authorization?apiKey=****&alias=****&login=****&password=****"
$.get(url, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

i'm getting this in my console this error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://demo.software.travel/gptp/api/authorization?apiKey=****&alias=****&login=****&password=****. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://travellights.net, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://travellights.net' is therefore not allowed access.

i'm trying to see questions here to solve it but i didn't get what i need to change, this is annoying actually.

> [The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343384/the-access-control-allow-origin-header-contains-multiple-values)
>
> ### this solved by asp.net web.congif

By the way i'm using **CHROME BROWSER** any help i appreciate.

**UPDATE** response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:origin, x-requested-with, Content-Type, accept, Token
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://travellights.net
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:close
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 02 Jun 2016 16:41:18 GMT
Server:nginx/1.1.19
Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=51FEE1A1206B9B481DD3EEA4167A9256; Path=/gptp
Vary:Origin
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-UA-Compatible:IE=EmulateIE7
```

Request Headers:

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ar;q=0.6,en-GB;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Host:demo.software.travel
Origin:http://travellights.net
Referer:http://travellights.net/b2b/Pages/login?
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: is `http://demo.software.travel` yours?

Comment: it's now mine :( but i can talk to the support and they r very responsive

Comment: Now yours, or not..

Comment: The problem is with the server you are requesting data from, if it isn't yours all you can do is present them with the error you are getting. It's pretty descriptive as far as what needs to be changed.

Comment: @KevinB this problem is present when i use ajax request, but when i use the normal get form action everything going very straight

Comment: Form posts and gets aren't subject to the same origin policy.

Comment: okay i'm talking to the support now, thank you for your time :)

Comment: but another question if i use CRUL do it goes with same error ?

Comment: Curl also isn't subject to the same origin policy. Ajax only. I frames are also restricted, but a bit differently.

Comment: then it won't give the same problem :) thank you very much bro :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are attempting to do Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) which is a mechanism that allows restricted resources on a web page to be requested from another domain outside the domain from which the resource originated. (such as accessing fonts or JSON files).

Browsers restrict your access to resources from other origins as of Same-origin policy as a security measure for internet users.

To get around this issue you have to options:

1. allow CORS on the domain http://demo.software.travel
   (but there is are security concerns, more description about it here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTML5_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Cross_Origin_Resource_Sharing)

Enable CORS on the server to be able to access other domains through.
this can be done by adding the following headers to responses:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://travellights.net
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept`

2. if you are not granted resource sharing with that domain, you are allowed to use JSONP for read only operations (JSONP is inherently read-only)

JSONP wraps a JSON object in a callback, which technically makes the request a non-restricted resource (a script tag) hence can be shared across domains.

it can be done via vanilla js by adding a script tag onto the page.

```
function process(data) {
    // do stuff with JSON
}

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = '//domainURL?callback=process'

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

or you can use jquery to achieve the same:

```
$.ajax({enter code here
    url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql",
    jsonp: "callback",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {
        q: "select title,abstract,url from search.news where query=\"cat\"",
        format: "json"
    },
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response ); // server response
    }
});
```

jquery documentation: https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/

Answer (score 9):

If you set ["Full" CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55584963/860099) (with OPTION pre-request) on in nginx by add 'access-control-allow-origin *' and independently you add that header (for [Simple CORS](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Flowchart_showing_Simple_and_Preflight_XHR.svg) - without OPTION pre-request) to each response in SERVER (eg. php):

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
```

Then you will get this problem. Solution: remove code which add this header in server if already you add this header in your nginx config :)

I found this advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38963508/860099)