# How to set the value of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header based on a list of allowed origins?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2, cors

I have read quite a lot of posts but none of them worked though.

I have ec2 setup in aws installed with ubuntu 16.04 and nginx. went into the `site-available` /  `site-enabled` to `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` allowing one domain access, but how can I add more than one domain access?

I would get multiple values error if I add more than one accress.
Lots posts are about php such as

[NGINX 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38963180/nginx-access-control-allow-origin-header-contains-multiple-values)

even though I am not using php but I have tried using the code above but does not work though.

is anyone able to give me a hand or direct me how this can be done on server?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can conditionally cause the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header to be sent, with the right value, by adding something like the following to your nginx config.

```
location / {
  set $is_allowed_origin "";
  if ($http_origin = "https://some.allowed.origin") {
    set $is_allowed_origin "true";
  }
  if ($http_origin = "https://another.allowed.origin") {
    set $is_allowed_origin "true";
  }
  if ($is_allowed_origin = "true") {
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "$http_origin";
  }
}
```

That’ll cause `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://some.allowed.origin` to be sent if the value of the `Origin` request header in the request is `https://some.allowed.origin`, and will cause `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://another.allowed.origin` to be sent if the `Origin` is `https://another.allowed.origin`, etc.

And if the value of the `Origin` request header is neither `https://some.allowed.origin` or `https://another.allowed.origin`, then no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` would be sent.