# How to set/edit "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in response-header for "OPTIONS request method" in moqui frameword?

Tags: angular, cors, moqui

I'm building website with font-end that is written by Angular and it send request to back-end (Moqui) through out Rest-API. My website require User authenticated to use features, so every request is sent from front-end, I must add attribute "**withCredentials: true**" to make Angular append **JSESSIONID** from Cookie to request (server will use JSSESSIONID to get info about logged user).

However, Angular always send HTTP OPTIONS Request first to check CORS policy, and the attribute '**Access-Control-Allow-Origin**' in response header for this request have value is **"*"**,

so Angular throw the error "**Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.**"

How can I edit attribute "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" for the OPTIONS-method request, or any solution better than edit it? Please help me, I spend amount of time to find the solution but not resolved now!

Comment: If https://github.com/moqui/moqui-framework/search?q=access-control-allow-origin&unscoped_q=access-control-allow-origin is the source your Moqui system is running, then the answer seems to be that you can’t change the value that gets set for the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header without editing the source — because the `*` value is hardcoded into the source.

Comment: Where the souce code file I must edit to change it??

Comment: Actually I think what would likely be most productive for is to report to Moqui. See https://www.moqui.org/docs/moqui/Community+Guide#questions-and-support and https://www.moqui.org/docs/moqui/Issue+and+Pull+Request+Guide and https://www.moqui.org/vapps/my/User/Request. Otherwise, I’m not familiar with Moqui at all but just based on searching through the source code at GitHub, if you were the change the sources, I think a place to start would be `moqui-framework/framework/src/main/groovy/org/moqui/impl/util/RestSchemaUtil.groovy`. You’d then need to rebuild the code from your patched source.

Comment: @sideshowbarker: thank you for your response, but RestSchemaUtil.groovy is not cause of problem, Angular always send preflight request with OPTIONS method to check CORS proxy, and because I use nginx to mapping url from client to server, perhaps I should edit config in nginx to change attribute **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**, isn't it?

Comment: yeah see the answers at https://stackoverflow.com/a/44600395/441757 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/44422480/441757