# Cors Origin in Direct Path in laravel when calling images

Tags: php, laravel, angular, cors, virtual-reality

now I build web application using laravel 5.2 as webserivce and angular2 as front page
I use VR Library from http://cdn.pannellum.org
My Issue When I call link Of Iamge from my database like mywebsite.com/public/Images/photo7.png
return to me this message

> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5565' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

but I Handled this issue before I start project to transfer data from laravel and angular but when I call my images from direct Path return to me this message

Comment: can someone answer this question? I have the same problem.

Comment: put this in .htaccess in public folder 

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>

Comment: @KamgaSimoJunior I made answer below

Answer (score 1):

**Laravel 5 (L5)**: In my project in, when I return image (file) and want to avoid CORS i use following code (I change it a little by hand without testing but it should work):

```
private function responseFile($filePath, $fileMimeType,  $originalFileName) {

    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type' => $fileMimeType,
        //'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="'. $attachment->org_name . '"', - this header is added automaticaly
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" => request()->getSchemeAndHttpHost() // allow CORS (e.g. for images)
    );

    return response()->download($filePath, $originalFileName, $headers);
}
```

In this solution you don't need to touch  apache **.htaccess** file (or nginx config files) at all (if you do it it will cause errors with headers duplication) - because in this case we use so called [Simple CORS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests).

You can also read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46917668/860099) to avoid other problems which can cause that CORS error.

Answer (score 0):

Try these methods:

1. Install and config Cors from [enter link description here](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors)
2. Add Cors mode

```javascript
fetch(url,{mode:"cors"})
                    .then(res => res.blob())
                    .then(blob => {
                        const file = new File([blob], 'dot.png', {type:'image/png'});
                        console.log(file);
                    });
```

3. Resource from [enter link description here](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/fetching-images-with-the-fetch-api-fb8761ed27b2)

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel 9 :**
I got same issue when Images are not loading on Flutter app .
add these lines .htaccess file on root outside public folder :

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range"
    Header set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Length,Content-Range"
```

Add these lines in Config cors  :

```
{ 'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie','public/storage/images/*','/public/storage/images/*'],
}
```

run this commands on ubuntu server :

```
{ sudo a2enmod headers }
```