# The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Header Contains Multiple Values. However I Only Have One Value Defined in the Header?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cors

The following error throws for me when making a request:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'My Server URL' from origin 'Server Name' has been 
blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple
values 'Server Name, *', but only one is allowed.
```

However in my WebApiConfig.cs file I have defined the CORS policy as follows:

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("MyServerName", "Content-Type", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

I have defined only one value *MyServerName*, yet the error thrown defines it as `'Server Name, *'`

**UPDATE:**

When disabling my CORS definition in my WebApiConfig.cs file I recieve the following error when making a request:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'My Server URL' from origin 'Server Name' has been 
blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in
the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is
'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is 
controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

I do not have CORS defined in my Web.config file.

**UPDATE 2**

My Access-Control-Allow-Origin value was being defined in my IIS, after changing it and running it, it thinks the value is ''.

Comment: You are setting the header in more than one place, apparently.  Are you also setting it in your web.config?

Comment: If the header is set multiple times, your browser combines their values together.  So here you are setting the header with `MyServerName`, and someplace else, you're setting the header with `*`.  The browser is combining them together.  You can observe the dupe headers in your browser's network tab.

Comment: @TheGreatZab could you post  your web.config settings as well if you have any related to cors?

Comment: I don't recall defining it in my Web.config file, I will go through it and make sure. UPDATE: I do not have it defined in my web.config however I tried commenting out my current definition and the error thrown is telling me there is a wildcard '*' defined somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summing up from [The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343384/the-access-control-allow-origin-header-contains-multiple-values) there are multiple ways to add CORS and you possibly have more than one:

1. The way you are doing it.
2. By calling `app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);`
3. By adding it in web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

4. And by using the Cors attribute.
5. IIS or other configuration on the web server. Restart the app pool and it should work.

Comment: I do not have it defined in my web.config however I tried commenting out my current definition and the error thrown is telling me there is a wildcard '*' defined somewhere.

Comment: Do you have any filters? It might be added there. It might even be added by your web server.

Comment: No filters, I'm not sure how I would have it added in my web server.

Comment: @TheGreatZab Search your code for the word "origin", case insenstive search.  It's there, somewhere.  Don't just search .cs files, also search config files.

Comment: If it's iis, it might be in the website level configuration

Comment: It is IIS, I will look into it there, do you know where exactly I might find it on IIS?

Comment: Any web config. Possibly root of the application site https://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html

Comment: So I found where it was defined and it did say '*' but when I changed it to the correct value I would get an error saying the value is '', so when I renabled it in my WebApiConfig.cs it would then say I have it defined twice :(.

Comment: If it is in iis, remove it from there and keep it only in the webapiconfig. You need to also restart app pool for the settings to take place for sure

Comment: This has resolved my issue thank you, please update your answer and I will accept it.