# ReactJS cors "The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values"

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess, cors

**Scenario**

I am using `fetch` to gather json from my remote apache server. In the beginning I was receiving the following CORS violation:

> Access to fetch at
>   'http://dev.mediajackagency.com/clients/dawna/row/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/bw.jpg'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I overcame this issue by enabling CORS in the server's `.htaccess` file for this project

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
```

Now I'm getting a different CORS violation of

> Access to fetch at
>   'http://some.domain/some/endpoint'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*,
>   http://localhost:3000', but only one is allowed. Have the server send
>   the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your
>   needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with
>   CORS disabled.

**Question**

How can I find where the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is getting set for `localhost:3000` ? I've done a full index and search for strings related to cors, headers, etc etc with no luck. All ideas are appreciated.

***Extra***

- Via `npm start` the second ACAO value is `localhost:3000` but via `npm build` the second ACAO value is `localhost` so the second value appears to be dynamic and restricted to React
- Adding a `proxy` value to `package.json` doesn't appear to help at all

Comment: I suggest that you go through [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors) CORS error list and try to see what is causing your issue.

Comment: If you have access to Apache config file for your website, check if the CORS configuration is already there maybe your `.htaccess` config causing this error to be returned, same as this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343384/the-access-control-allow-origin-header-contains-multiple-values#answer-55027555

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ultimately could not decide if [CRA](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html)'s dev node server was creating this issue (by adding 'localhost:3000' as an allowed origin) or if I'm just not as good with `.htaccess` files as I thought. Regardless here is what finally ended up working:

**API server's .htaccess**

```
# allows image files to bypass cors @jkr
<Files *.jpg>
  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
  Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
</Files>

#always allow preflight to pass @jkr
<LimitExcept OPTIONS>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
</LimitExcept>
```