# Spring Cloud Gateway - CORS Preflight with React <> Spring Cloud Gateway <> NodeJS

Tags: reactjs, cors, spring-cloud-gateway

I am trying to setup a Cloud Gateway between React App and NodeJS application

Below is error I am getting on ReactApp:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/graphql' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I am already tried below link, as much may be with newer version of Cloud Gateway it is not working.

Attempt #1:

```
spring.cloud.gateway.globalcors.cors-configurations.[/**].allowedOrigins=*
spring.cloud.gateway.globalcors.cors-configurations.[/**].allowedMethods=*
```

With this I was getting Header issue so I added:

```
spring.cloud.gateway.globalcors.cors-configurations.[/**].allowedHeaders=*
```

I am getting below error:

```
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:3000, *', but only one is allowed.
```

Attempt #2:

I tried adding the following bean:

```
@Bean
  Function<GatewayFilterSpec, UriSpec> brutalCorsFilters() {
    return f -> f
        .setResponseHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        .setResponseHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*")
        .setResponseHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "*");
  }
```

But still no luck

Repo: https://github.com/shah-smit/quizroulette-spring-cloud-api-gateway

Comment: Nevermind found it -- if you check the github link it will solves it

Answer (score 0):

Please check your configuration carefully, it should be your configuration that caused multiple values, refer to this
[The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343384/the-access-control-allow-origin-header-contains-multiple-values)

Maybe you can debug your code and find out where 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' becomes two values.