# Spring Gateway Request blocked by CORS (The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values, but only one is allowed)

Tags: java, spring-boot, cors, api-gateway, spring-cloud-gateway

I have created a gateway API (spring boot) to route to a number of backend services (spring boot applications) for the frontend (Typescript), but I keep getting CORS error when the frontend tries to hit the Gateway API, even though it works fine on Postman.

This is the error i got on the console:

Access to fetch at 'https://gatway-api-ip-address:port/level/global' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:3000, http://localhost:3000', but only one is allowed. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Here's what I have inside the Gateway API, application.yml:

```
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Credentials Access-Control-Allow-Origin
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins:
            - "http://localhost:3000"
            - "http://localhost:8000"
            - "http://frontend-ip-address:port"
            allowCredentials: true
            allowedMethods:
              - GET
              - POST
              - DELETE
              - GET
              - OPTIONS
            allowedHeaders: "*"
```

Note: that the IP address for each backend service, frontend service and gateway API is the same as they're hosted on one Digital Ocean server.

Note: I have issued a self-signed ssl certificate for the gateway api

Comment: See this answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343384/the-access-control-allow-origin-header-contains-multiple-values

Comment: It's happening from your frontend application and not spring. You need to change code on the frontend side.

Comment: My guess is that your service that's behind the gateway is also configured with CORS and the `DedupeResponseHeader` isn't filtering the duplicates out properly. Can you show us the CORS headers from the perspective of the webbrowser?

Comment: @AnishB. What do you think is the proper solution for my case

Comment: @AnishB. could you explain how?

Comment: @g00glen00b you're right, the services behind the gateway are also configured with CORS.

here's the response headers on the console:
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:
true

Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
*

Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
http://localhost:3000

Comment: now the error has changed into:

Access To Fetch At 'https://gatway-api-ip-address:port/level/global' From Origin 'http://Localhost:3000' Has Been Blocked By CORS Policy: Response To Preflight Request Doesn't Pass Access Control Check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Header Is Present On The Requested Resource. If An Opaque Response Serves Your Needs, Set The Request's Mode To 'No-Cors' To Fetch The Resource With CORS Disabled.

but i haven't changed anything in application.yml